# Why are my custom fonts in Android app replaced by default font in release mode?

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin.android, release, truetype

When I build and deploy in Debug mode a Xamarin.android application which contains custom fonts everything is OK. I can see custom ttf typeface in app.
But, when I build and deploy the same application in Release mode, then when I run it I see default font in it.
Are there some required permissions which should be added in app properties for custom fonts to be visible in app?

Here is how I use fonts in my app:

1. Convert method in converter class:

   ```
   protected override Typeface Convert(string fontName, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!fontName.StartsWith(@"font/")) fontName = @"font/" + fontName;
           if (!fontName.EndsWith(".ttf")) fontName += ".ttf";

           if (!_cache.ContainsKey(fontName))
           {
               _cache[fontName] = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, fontName);
           }

           return _cache[fontName];
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Android.Util.Log.Error("AndroidFont", e.ToString());

           return Typeface.Default;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Item in AXML

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#ffffff"              
             >
   <TextView
     android:layout_width="180dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
     local:MvxBind="Typeface StringToFont('Lato'), Converter=StringToFontConverter" /></LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Registering converter in Setup.cs

   ```
   protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
   {
       registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<View>("StringToFont", view => new BackgroundBinding(view)));
   }
   ```

TTF Fonts lie in Assets/fonts directory. I work on Visual Studio Community 2015 (C#).

It all works fine, but only in Debug mode. When I switch to Release mode, my font (Lato) is replaced by default Android font. Why?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create MvxViewFontBinding

   ```
   public abstract class MvxViewFontBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
   {
       protected TextView TextView => (TextView)base.Target;
       public MvxViewFontBinding(TextView view) : base(view)
       {
       }

       public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

       public override Type TargetType => typeof(Android.Graphics.Typeface);
   }
   ```
2. Create MvxViewCustomFontBinding

   ```
   public class MvxViewCustomFontBinding : MvxViewFontBinding
   {
       public MvxViewCustomFontBinding(TextView view) : base(view)
       {
       }

       protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
       {
           var textView = (TextView)target;
           textView?.SetTypeface((Android.Graphics.Typeface)value, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Registering in Setup.cs

   ```
   protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
   {
       registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("CustomFont", textView => new MvxViewCustomFontBinding(textView)));
       base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
   }
   ```
4. You can bind it on axml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#ffffff">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="180dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
       local:MvxBind="CustomFont StringToFont('Lato')" /></LinearLayout>
   ```